# How to ensure my extension's TypoScript is loaded in every case?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a TYPO3 extension and have TypoScript in there.
For some reason I want to ensure the TypoScript is loaded when activating the extension, without including static templates in TYPO3 backend.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Be careful with the following How-To. You should know what you're doing!**

For TYPO3 extensions it's possible to add two files in the root of your extension: `ext_typoscript_constants.typoscript` and `ext_typoscript_setup.typoscript`.

In `ext_typoscript_constants.typoscript` you can add constants.
In `ext_typoscript_setup.typoscript` you can add the TypoScript setup.

When adding these files with TypoScript, it will be loaded when the extension is installed and activated.

I use this possibility only for site package extensions where the complete page rendering and configuration is included.

See: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/FilesAndLocations/Index.html

Comment: I prefer another way to implement all required TypoScript at root level https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/Snippets/2017/Index.html#root-typoscript-without-database